# DTD parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I have a given DTD, i.e.

```
<!ELEMENT dblp (article|inproceedings|proceedings)*>
<!ENTITY % field "author|editor|title|booktitle|pages">

<!ELEMENT article       (%field;)*>
<!ATTLIST article
                    key CDATA #REQUIRED
                    mdate CDATA #IMPLIED
                    publtype CDATA #IMPLIED
                    reviewid CDATA #IMPLIED
                    rating CDATA #IMPLIED
>
```

I need to convert this to an XML form, i.e.

```
<element>
    <name>article</name>
    <attribues>
         <attr>key</attr>
         <attr>mdate</attr>
         ...
    </attributes>
</element>
...
```

I'd rather not parse the DTD myself. I was looking for a library, but most DOM/SAX libs handle XML only..  I did found NekoDTD, but it's almost 8yo and not updated...

So what do u recommend?

Comment: Try a google search of "dtd parser"  the top 4 hits are all open source dtd parsers for java.

Comment: Which particular Java library do u recommend? I need smt that is available on public MVN repos

Answer (score 1):

> I need to convert type definitions from a DTD to a more Java-Bean
>   friendly XML form.

You could use the JAXB XJC with the `-dtd` flag tool to generate a domain model from the DTD.

```
xjc -p blog.log4j -d out -dtd log4j.dtd
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-dtd.html

Comment: I do not need a class / an instance.. I need to produce an XML file :-(

Comment: In your comment to the answer given by @Mentezza you stated you needed a `Java-Bean friendly XML form`.  This answer describes how you could generate a Java-Bean model that could be used to produce the desired XML.  If this isn't what you are looking for let me know and I will delete this answer.

Comment: Running Xjc can be a useful technique.  Using xjc -p tgt  -d out -dtd 01-02-16.dtd,  where 01-02-16.dtd is the full UML DTD (slightly modified to fix name space clashes on two elements)  one can  instantly generate 386 machine-readable Java files for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there is an infinity of valid XML files according to a given DTD. The framework you are looking for will just generate a small subset (but it may be sufficient for your purpose: what is it, anyway?)

Comment: I need to convert type definitions from a DTD to a more Java-Bean friendly XML form. Note - I dont need the DTD for validation of any XMLs whatsoever - I need it as a basis for type definitions in my app